# iPhone:How to combine multiple video files into single video file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

In my app on the click of the button my animation starts and video recording also starts but again I tap the same button my animation pauses and my video recording file is generated then again I tap the same button at that time animation starts but new file for recording the video is generated.

How can I combine these 2 files into single file so that my video recording works fine...

Answer (score 1):

you have to use AvAssetExportSession and AVMutableComposition for this.